# How to map values from two lists when substring matches

Tags: python, list

I have values in two different lists:

```
list1 = [
    "1003_0123_20200821091044_ion_fri_jl.dat",
    "8005_0086_20200821090605_ion_fri_jl.dat",
    "1003_0123_20200821091999_ion_fri_jl.dat",
]

list2 = [
    "IMM CCA CADD USD GAAP_202103311352_20200821091999_FRI",
    "ICM CCA CADD USD GAAP_202103311352_20200821090605_FRI",
    "CCA CTAD USD GAAPA_202103311352_20200821091044_FRI",
]
```

I want to pair the values that have the same substring obtained by `str.split('_')[2]`. For instance, the first element in `list1` has the substring `20200821091044`, which matches the third element in `list2`. Then I want to have the matched values like this:

```
[
    (
        "1003_0123_20200821091044_ion_fri_jl.dat",
        "CCA CTAD USD GAAPA_202103311352_20200821091044_FRI",
    ),
    (
        "8005_0086_20200821090605_ion_fri_jl.dat",
        "ICM CCA CADD USD GAAP_202103311352_20200821090605_FRI",
    ),
    (
        "1003_0123_20200821091999_ion_fri_jl.dat",
        "IMM CCA CADD USD GAAP_202103311352_20200821091999_FRI",
    ),
]
```

or in a dictionary format.

Comment: You've described the problem so well, including a tiny snippet for how you want to match them but not taken any effort to try something (code) with it.

Comment: @GG. Your edit to the question changes the meaning of the OP's post quite a bit. For starters, they don't want merely a substring match, they want to match the 2th element of split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the first list, extract the substring, loop over the second list and find the match.

```
results = []

for x in list1:
    substring = x.split("_")[2]

    for y in list2:
        if substring in y:
            results.append((x, y))
```

Comment: While your answer works in the this case, it's a bit "fragile" wrt a change in the data. Specifically, the last number-group in `list1` could match with an element in `list2` which has that as the first number-group and not the second number-group, as originally wanted in the question. Granted, in this case the numbers in `list2` are not the same length so that collision won't occur - but that's an implicit hidden assumption in the solution. Perhaps you could add _"if the first number-group of `list2` can never match with the number-group in `list1` then do a simple `substr in string` match."_

Answer (score 0):

A previous edit of your question said *"or in a dictionary format"* which is what I'll use here:

```py
import collections

grouped = collections.defaultdict(list)
for item in list1+list2:  # or itertools.chain(list1, list2)
    grouped[item.split('_')[2]].append(item)
```

`grouped` is:

```py
defaultdict(list,
            {'20200821091044': ['1003_0123_20200821091044_ion_fri_jl.dat',
              'CCA CTAD USD GAAPA_202103311352_20200821091044_FRI'],
             '20200821090605': ['8005_0086_20200821090605_ion_fri_jl.dat',
              'ICM CCA CADD USD GAAP_202103311352_20200821090605_FRI'],
             '20200821091999': ['1003_0123_20200821091999_ion_fri_jl.dat',
              'IMM CCA CADD USD GAAP_202103311352_20200821091999_FRI']})
```

Or `list(grouped.values())` to get it in a list of pairs:

```py
[['1003_0123_20200821091044_ion_fri_jl.dat',
  'CCA CTAD USD GAAPA_202103311352_20200821091044_FRI'],
 ['8005_0086_20200821090605_ion_fri_jl.dat',
  'ICM CCA CADD USD GAAP_202103311352_20200821090605_FRI'],
 ['1003_0123_20200821091999_ion_fri_jl.dat',
  'IMM CCA CADD USD GAAP_202103311352_20200821091999_FRI']]
```